# Very slow SQL join, with limited amount of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

We have a very slow running piece of SQL, and I was wondering if anyone has any
advice on speeding it up.

We are collecting the data from a large number of tables (21) into a single table
for later processing. The tables are temporary tables, and exist only for the query.

All the tables share three columns (`USN`, `DATASET`, and `INTERNAL_ID`), and
the combination of the three is unique in each table, but the same values exist
in all the tables. It it possible that `INTERNAL_ID` is also unique, but I am not sure.

Each table contains six rows of data, and the output table also contains six rows.

I.e, each table has the following data, the first three columns being the same in each table, and the remaining columns contain different data for each table.

```
USN DATASET INTERNAL_ID <more stuff>
20  BEN     67          ...
20  APP     68          ...
30  BEN     70          ...
30  BEN     75          ...
50  CRM     80          ...
70  CRM     85          ...
```

The server is SQL 2008 R2 with 4 x 2.3GHz cores, 32GB memory, which is sitting
idle and should be more than adequate.

The `INSERT INTO` query itself takes approximately 3 seconds.

What can I do to either find out the reason for the code being so slow, or to speed it up. If there a maximum number of joins that I should do in a single query?

```
CREATE TABLE #output (
  USN         INT,
  DATASET     VARCHAR(150),
  INTERNAL_ID INT,
  MASTER_DATA INT,
  EX1_DATA    INT,
  EX2_DATA    INT,
  EX3_DATA    INT,
-- More columns
)
```

The full output table consists of 247 columns, with 71 integers, 11 floats, 44 datetimes and 121 varchars with a total size of 16,996 characters!!! I would expect each varchar to have around 20-30 characters.

```
CREATE TABLE #master (
  USN         INT,
  DATASET     VARCHAR(150),
  INTERNAL_ID INT,
  MASTER_DATA INT,
-- More columns
)

CREATE TABLE #ex1 (
  USN         INT,
  DATASET     VARCHAR(150),
  INTERNAL_ID INT,
  EX1_DATA    INT,
-- More columns
)
CREATE TABLE #ex2 (
  USN         INT,
  DATASET     VARCHAR(150),
  INTERNAL_ID INT,
  EX2_DATA    INT,
-- More columns
)

-- Repeat for ex3 .. ex20
```

Most of the `ex` tables are 10-11 columns with a couple in the 20-30 column range.

```
-- Insert data into master, ex1..ex20

INSERT INTO #output(USN, DATASET, INTERNAL_ID, MASTER_DATA, EX1_DATA, EX2_DATA, ...)
  SELECT #master.USN, #master.DATASET, #master.INTERNAL_ID, #master.MASTER_DATA, #ex1.EX1_DATA, #ex2.EX2_DATA, ...
  FROM
    #master
    LEFT JOIN #ex1 ON #master.USN = #ex1.USN AND
                      #master.DATASET = #ex1.DATASET AND
                      #master.INTERNAL_ID = #ex1.INTERNAL_ID
    LEFT JOIN #ex2 ON #master.USN = #ex2.USN AND
                      #master.DATASET = #ex2.DATASET AND
                      #master.INTERNAL_ID = #ex2.INTERNAL_ID
    -- contine until we hit ex20
```

Comment: Something doesn't make sense.  Your `#output` table has three columns.  I would expect you to use `union all` or to have 63 columns in the output.  But then again, why would you want to repeat the same three values over and over -- perhaps with `NULL` values -- for the output data set?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the query optimizer struggle with too many joins as well. You don't have primary keys on those temporary tables, right? Adding those *might* help (or it might make it worse). You could also try making some intermediate tables, or use 20 separate `merge` statements instead of one big `insert`. In any case, MS SQL isn't really the best choice for this kind of DBF-style tables. Why are you trying to put all those columns together? Maybe you could e.g. output a XML instead or something?

Comment: Collect statistics on each of the tables using DBMS_STATS.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I obviously removed too much when trying to simplify the problem. There are a lot of extra columns in each table.

Comment: @SimonCallan . . . How large are the rest of the column in the table?  Six rows would  not normally benefit from an index, but if the other columns are actually really big, a covering index would help performance.

Comment: [I've built an SQLFiddle for this question](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33988/1). Given the data above, and adding only a single "extra" field to each table, the query runs in 129 milliseconds (as reported by SQLFiddle - wall time is longer, which I attribute to HTML formatting, etc). I suspect adding more fields will slow the query down.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've added extra details. The tables are a lot bigger than I first thought.

Comment: IMHO,Instead of asking about reason for slow query,you should be discussing about your requirement in first place .Output Table containing 247 columns and so and so,is something which is not convincing,not even from data mining point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I would add index on each of temporary tables according to the data (unique).

I would start with index on both `int` columns only, and if it is not enough I would add `DATASET` column to the index.

And sometimes the order you JOIN tables make (or made in previous version of MS SQL) a huge difference, so start JOINs from the smallest table (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

1. If there are more than just one row with given USN, DATASET, INTERNAL_ID in each of these tables, the size of resulting table will grow exponentially with each join sequence. If this is the case, consider rework your statement, or replace with a number of simpler ones.
2. Consider using an index for a row in join statement with highest cardinality in each of #ex1-20 tables (or even complex index for two columns or the entire trio)
3. And, of course, if there are some constraints in resulting temporary table, you need an index for each such constraint as well.